# How to force SaveAs instead Save

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prevent user to save the workbook with the same name as it is opened with, and to offer SaveAs option.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If ThisWorkbook.Name = "abc" Then
Cancel = True
SaveAsUI = True
End If
```

Also tried

```
 If ThisWorkbook.Name = "abc" Then SaveAsUI = True
```

This code doesn't work. SaveAs dialog doesn't appear.

Next try

```
If ThisWorkbook.Name = "abc" Then ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = True
'Error - can't assign to read only property.
```

Comment: Set the attribute of the workbook to read-only to force a `SaveAs`. This method means you are protected without relying on VBA handling.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly` is a read-only attribute (see f1-help) - you have to use a different method in order to make the workbook read-only, eg my `Workbooks.Open` suggestion or the `ChangeFileAccess` answer from @brettdj below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to test for a particular filename only - say `abc.xlsm` then the code below will stop the `Save` (but pass `SaveAs`) then set the `ReadOnly` attribute to False so `Save` can't be used again on this file in this session

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not SaveAsUI Then
    If ThisWorkbook.Name = "abc.xlsm" Then
        Cancel = True
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I have two suggestions, but in order to know which is best you have to tell us more details about the surrounding code and how you open/create files etc.

1. Use a template. If you put your code in a template and add a new workbook, it cannot be saved without the SaveAs dialog.
2. Make the workbook read only at opening. This can be done in a lot of ways, depending on the design of your project (eg `Workbooks.Open` with `ReadOnly` parameter).

Comment: please see my updated question. The same error appears if I put the code in `Workbook.Open` event

Answer (score 3):

The other answer (read only or template) are both good suggestions

However, if you really want to code it, try this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fName As String
    If ThisWorkbook.Name  "abc.xlsm" Then 
        If Not SaveAsUI Then
            fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
            If fName = "False" Then
                MsgBox "File NOT saved", vbOKOnly
                Cancel = True
            Else
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: coded for Excel 2007/2010 (`If ThisWorkbook.Name  "abc.xlsm" Then`)

You woill need to change if using Excel 2003